# How to add glow in godot 4?

Tags: game-development, godot

Currently, Godot 4 alpha 13.
and I am trying to add glow.
but whenever I am trying to change the `environment.background.BGMode` to canvas,
everything on the screen goes invisible.

am I doing something wrong or it is a bug in Godot 4?

Comment: This could be related to https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/52467

Comment: Yes, it is. Should I delete this question?

Comment: Not necessarily. There might still be a workaround which would be a valid answer. Or it could be answered after the issue is fixed. You can still delete it on your own discretion while it has no answer.